# How to extract text sections into separate files named based on id?

Tags: xml, shell, loops, svg, sed

Given a text file containing a series repetitive text sections, how should I go about extracting those sections and storing them in individual text files whose name is derived from every section's id?

- All sections begin with `<?xml` and end with `</svg>`.
- All sections have an id tag that should serve as the basis for their name.

I am not sure how two sed REGEXes would need to be combined within a `for loop` to achieve this.

---

Original.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="France" width="1500" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 3 2">
<rect width="3" height="2" fill="#009246"/>
<rect width="2" height="2" x="1" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="1" height="2" x="2" fill="#ce2b37"/>
</svg>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Italy" width="900" height="600">
<rect width="900" height="600" fill="#ED2939"/>
<rect width="600" height="600" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="300" height="600" fill="#002395"/>
</svg>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Ireland" width="1200" height="600">
<rect fill="#169b62" width="1200" height="600" />
<rect fill="#fff" x="400" width="800" height="600" />
<rect fill="#ff883e" x="800" width="400" height="600" />
</svg>
```

---

**Result:**

France.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="France" width="1500" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 3 2">
<rect width="3" height="2" fill="#009246"/>
<rect width="2" height="2" x="1" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="1" height="2" x="2" fill="#ce2b37"/>
</svg>
```

Italy.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Italy" width="900" height="600">
<rect width="900" height="600" fill="#ED2939"/>
<rect width="600" height="600" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="300" height="600" fill="#002395"/>
</svg>
```

Ireland.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Ireland" width="1200" height="600">
<rect fill="#169b62" width="1200" height="600" />
<rect fill="#fff" x="400" width="800" height="600" />
<rect fill="#ff883e" x="800" width="400" height="600" />
</svg>
```

Comment: SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Any time you find yourself considering a solution where `two sed REGEXes would need to be combined within a for loop` stop and realize you have gone off the rails as that is never the best solution to any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and xmlstarlet:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do

  # fill variable with all lines and append newline to every line
  svg="$svg$line"$'\n'

  # last line?
  if [[ $line =~ \</svg\> ]]; then

    # extract attribute from xml
    svgfile=$(xmlstarlet select -N x='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' --template --value-of '//x:svg/@id' <<< "$svg")

    # remove trailing newline and output xml to new file
    echo -e "${svg:0:-1}" > "${svgfile}.svg"

    unset svg
  fi
done < Original.svg
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS to separate the files into valid XML per SVG section, co-processes to let us print records to xmlstarlet and read the output, the second arg to `close()` to let us close the pipe to xmlstarlet so it processes the input, and xmlstarlet to actually read the XML:

```
$ cat ../tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS  = "</svg>[[:space:]]*"
    ORS = ""
    xmlParser = "xmlstarlet select -N x=\047http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\047 --template --value-of \047//x:svg/@id\047"
}
RT != "" {
    $0 = $0 RT

    print |& xmlParser
    close(xmlParser,"to")

    if ( (xmlParser |& getline id) > 0 ) {
        print > (id ".svg")
    }
    close(xmlParser)
}
```

For example, where `file` contains the input text from the question:

```
$ ls
file  tst.awk

$ awk -f tst.awk file

$ ls
file  tst.awk  France.svg  Ireland.svg  Italy.svg

$ tail -n +1 *.svg
==> France.svg <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="France" width="1500" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 3 2">
<rect width="3" height="2" fill="#009246"/>
<rect width="2" height="2" x="1" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="1" height="2" x="2" fill="#ce2b37"/>
</svg>

==> Ireland.svg <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Ireland" width="1200" height="600">
<rect fill="#169b62" width="1200" height="600" />
<rect fill="#fff" x="400" width="800" height="600" />
<rect fill="#ff883e" x="800" width="400" height="600" />
</svg>

==> Italy.svg <==
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Italy" width="900" height="600">
<rect width="900" height="600" fill="#ED2939"/>
<rect width="600" height="600" fill="#fff"/>
<rect width="300" height="600" fill="#002395"/>
</svg>
```

It would fail if `</svg>` was inside a comment or a string and maybe other contexts that you don't seem to have. idk what you want to do if there is no `id` in the XML section so I'm just not printing the XML if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brittle but portable awk solution.

```
awk '
            {a[i++]=$0}
  /^<svg/   {for(f=1; f<=NF; f++) if($f~/^id=/) split($f, id, /["=]+/)}
  /^<\/svg/ {for(n=0; n<i; n++) print a[n] > (id[2] ".svg"); i=0}
' Original.svg
```

1. Put every line in an array indexed by increment
2. On lines beginning with `<svg`, split the third field into array `id` using one or more equals or double quote symbols.
3. On lines beginning with `</svg`, iterate over the array, printing every element (line) to a file named by concatenating the second result of our split `id[2]` with the file extension ".svg".

Answer (score -1):

Here is a consice awk script sovling your request.
Assuming there is consistent 6 lines file structure.

#### script.awk

```
{++line; lines = lines"\n"$0;}
NR%6 == 2 {id = substr($3, 5, length($3)-5)".svg"; next;}
NR%6 == 0 {
        print lines > id;
        line = 0; lines = "";
}
```

#### run command

```
awk -f script.awk Original.svg
```

If you need explanation request in comments.